# Why don't reads from /dev/zero count as IO_RBYTES?

Tags: linux, devices, io, null

I am emptying out a hard drive on some Linux 4.x OS using this command:

```
sudo sh -c 'pv -pterb /dev/zero > /dev/sda'
```

And I opened another tty and started `sudo htop` and noticed this:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI CPU%   RES   SHR   IO_RBYTES   IO_WBYTES S   TIME+  Command
 4598 root       20   0 15.5  1820  1596        4096    17223823 D  1:14.11 pv -pterb /dev/zero
```

The value for `IO_WBYTES` seems quite normal, but `IO_RBYTES` remains at 4 KiB and never changes.

I ran a few other programs, for example

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/zero
cat /dev/zero > /dev/zero
```

and was surprised to see none of them generates a lot of `IO_RBYTES` or `IO_WBYTES`.

I think this is not specific to any program, but why don't reads from `/dev/zero` and writes to `/dev/{zero,null}` count as I/O bytes?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you think they _should_ count as I/O?

Comment: @marcelm I think any input/output should count as I/O, including file R/W, network I/O and many more.

Comment: but those operations perform I/O to _hardware_ (disk, and the network card, respectively), and have to travel over some I/O bus (such as PCI-express), all of which can be a significant bottleneck. Writes to, say, `/dev/null` don't end up interfacing wich such hardware and don't clog I/O buses. Taken to the extreme; are reads/writes to/from memory also I/O? Of course, there is no hard delineation for these things, and it all depends on which perspective you take in these things, and how useful that perspective ends up being to you.

Comment: Note, my first comment was intended to provoke you (and others) to think about those perspectives, and find out why you're taking your perspective. I don't mean to insinuate you're wrong; I don't even think the situation is that black and white. But personally, I would be a lot more interested in I/O statistics to actual hardware (which may very well be a bottleneck) than to `/dev/{null,zero}` (which usually isn't a bottleneck). That's just my perspective though :)

Comment: @marcelm But I was initially thinking that any `read(2)` and `write(2)` counts as I/O, which is very reasonable in its own sense.

Comment: It is! But it's not the only reasonable expectation :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

They do count as I/O, but not of the type measured by the fields you’re looking at.

In `htop`, `IO_RBYTES` and `IO_WBYTES` show the `read_bytes` and `write_bytes` fields from `/proc/<pid>/io`, and those fields measure bytes which go through the block layer. `/dev/zero` doesn’t involve the block layer, so reads from it don’t show up there.

To see I/O from `/dev/zero`, you need to look at the `rchar` and `wchar` fields in `/proc/<pid>/io`, which show up in `htop` as `RCHAR` and `WCHAR`:

> *rchar*: characters read
>
> The number of bytes which this task has caused to be
>                        read from storage.  This is simply the sum of bytes
>                        which this process passed to [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and similar system
>                        calls.  It includes things such as terminal I/O and is
>                        unaffected by whether or not actual physical disk I/O
>                        was required (the read might have been satisfied from
>                        pagecache).
>
> *wchar*: characters written
>
> The number of bytes which this task has caused, or
>                        shall cause to be written to disk.  Similar caveats
>                        apply here as with rchar.

See [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [`man 1 htop`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html) for details.

Comment: So it's `rchar` and `wchar` that count bytes from calls to `read(2)` and `write(2)`, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Talk about misleading phrasing on the description of _rchar_. Everything passed through `read()` most definitely isn't "read from _storage_"!

Comment: @ilkkachu by `storage` they mean "any conceivable bus line", regardless of whether the storage in question is physical or virtual or mmap'd or a virtual socket or in L1 cache -- it's just anything outside of that program's mapped memory including shared